# Ubuntu Budgie freezes during installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, freeze, ubuntu-budgie

I've been trying to install Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 (downloaded from the official site), but the installation freezes whenever i reach the place where i have to do Disk Partition. None of the partitions i have appear on the screen and it freezes when i press any of the options (create a new partions, delete ...)
Ubuntu runs perfectly on Live Mode and on my Virtual Machine.
I'm using MSI GF-63 8rd with Windows 10 already installed, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD with 16GB Intel Optane Memory (Rapid Storage Technology). Bios mode is already in UEFI (the other 2 options are Legacy and UEFI with CSM), and I've already disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot.